# Android Compass orientation on unreliable (Low pass filter)

Tags: android, algorithm, orientation, signal-processing, compass-geolocation

Im creating an application where i need to position a ImageView depending on the Orientation of the device. 
I use the values from a MagneticField and Accelerometer Sensors to calculate the device orientation with

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelerometerValues, magneticFieldValues)
SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, values);
double degrees = Math.toDegrees(values[0]);
```

My problem is that the positioning of the ImageView is very sensitive to changes in the orientation. Making the imageview constantly jumping around the screen. (because the degrees change)

I read that this can be because my device is close to things that can affect the magneticfield readings. But this is not the only reason it seems.

I tried downloading some applications and found that the "[3D compass](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-a0soft-gphone-acompass-zzzw.aspx)" and "[Compass](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-apksoftware-compass-qAC.aspx)" remains extremely steady in its readings (when setting the noise filter up), i would like the same behavior in my application.

I read that i can tweak the "noise" of my readings by adding a "**Low pass filter**", but i have no idea how to implement this (because of my lack of Math).

Im hoping someone can help me creating a more steady reading on my device, Where a little movement to the device wont affect the current orientation.
Right now i do a small

```
if (Math.abs(lastReadingDegrees - newReadingDegrees) > 1) { updatePosition() }
```

To filter abit of the noise. But its not working very well :)

Comment: Got my "repeated" answer deleted, but I thought it would genuinely help people because I know the pain of going through this sensor noise conundrum on Android. Anyway, for the people in the future, here's the solution that's working for me --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/39276888/1262089

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Though I havn't used the compass on Android, the basic processing shown below (in JavaScript) will probably work for you.

It's based on the low pass filter on the accelerometer that's recommended by the [Windows Phone team](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/09/08/using-the-accelerometer-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) with modifications to suit a compass (the cyclic behavior every 360").

I assume the compass reading is in degrees, a float between 0-360, and the output should be similar.

You want to accomplish 2 things in the filter:

> 1. If the change is small, to prevent gitter, gradually turn to that direction.
> 2. If the change is big, to prevent lag, turn to that direction immediatly (and it can be canceled if you want the compass to move only in a smooth way).

For that we will have 2 constants:

> 1. The easing float that defines how smooth the movement will be (1 is no smoothing and 0 is never updating, my default is 0.5). We will call it SmoothFactorCompass.
> 2. The threshold in which the distance is big enough to turn immediatly (0 is jump always, 360 is never jumping, my default is 30). We will call it SmoothThresholdCompass.

We have one variable saved across the calls, a float called oldCompass and it is the result of the algorithm.

So the variable defenition is:

```
var SmoothFactorCompass = 0.5;
var SmoothThresholdCompass = 30.0;
var oldCompass = 0.0;
```

and the function recieves newCompass, and returns oldCompass as the result.

```
if (Math.abs(newCompass - oldCompass) < 180) {
    if (Math.abs(newCompass - oldCompass) > SmoothThresholdCompass) {
        oldCompass = newCompass;
    }
    else {
        oldCompass = oldCompass + SmoothFactorCompass * (newCompass - oldCompass);
    }
}
else {
    if (360.0 - Math.abs(newCompass - oldCompass) > SmoothThresholdCompass) {
        oldCompass = newCompass;
    }
    else {
        if (oldCompass > newCompass) {
            oldCompass = (oldCompass + SmoothFactorCompass * ((360 + newCompass - oldCompass) % 360) + 360) % 360;
        } 
        else {
            oldCompass = (oldCompass - SmoothFactorCompass * ((360 - newCompass + oldCompass) % 360) + 360) % 360;
        }
    }
}
```

I see that the issue was opened 5 months ago and probably isn't relevant anymore, but I'm sure other programmers might find it useful.

Oded Elyada.

Comment: This gives me wierd results when the `oldCompass` is about 0 and the `newCompass` is 359.

Answer (score 19):

This lowpass filter works for angles in radians. Use the **add** function for each compass reading, then call **average** to get the average.

```
public class AngleLowpassFilter {

    private final int LENGTH = 10;

    private float sumSin, sumCos;

    private ArrayDeque<Float> queue = new ArrayDeque<Float>();

    public void add(float radians){

        sumSin += (float) Math.sin(radians);

        sumCos += (float) Math.cos(radians);

        queue.add(radians);

        if(queue.size() > LENGTH){

            float old = queue.poll();

            sumSin -= Math.sin(old);

            sumCos -= Math.cos(old);
        }
    }

    public float average(){

        int size = queue.size();

        return (float) Math.atan2(sumSin / size, sumCos / size);
    }
}
```

Use **`Math.toDegrees()`** or **`Math.toRadians()`** to convert.

Comment: Can you explain why you need all those trigonometrical functions here?

Comment: Hi Felix, You need the trig because a simple numeric average of a set of angles does not always represent the middle. Let's say your angles in degrees were [350,10] then your average would be (350+10)/2 = 180 (where the middle is actually 0). **Thanks for your edit too.**

Comment: Ok, yes that makes sense. And somehow the trigos solve this problem. :) And am I right that `average ()` returns the angle in degrees?

Comment: The return value is in radians (consistent with the input value and the trig functions). 

We use cos and sin to break the angle down into an [x,y] vector, because the average of these vectors *does* represent a midline.

Then we use atan2 to convert the vector back to an angle in radians.

Comment: Your implementation is exactly what I was looking for. Smooth even without interpolation animation.

Comment: I tried both: this way and Oded Elyada's way and I decided to choose this.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that, for example the average of 350 and 10 is not 180. My solution:

```
int difference = 0;
for(int i= 1;i <numberOfAngles;i++){
    difference += ( (angles[i]- angles[0] + 180 + 360 ) % 360 ) - 180;
}
averageAngle = (360 + angles[0] + ( difference / numberOfAngles ) ) % 360;
```

Answer (score 3):

A low pass filter (LPF) blocks fast changing signals and
allows only slow changes in the signals. This means any small
sudden changes will be ignored.

The standard way to implement this in software is to take a running average
of the last N samples and report that value. Start with N as small as 3 and
keep increasing N until you find sufficient smoothed out response in your app.

Do keep in mind that the higher you make N, slower the response of the system.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to this related question: [Smoothing data from a sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611599/help-smoothing-data-from-a-sensor/4611772#4611772)

A software low pass filter is basically a modified version of that. Indeed, in that answer I even provided this link to another related question: [Low pass filter software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344343/low-pass-filter-software)