# Smoothing the values of the Compass on Android devices

Tags: android, augmented-reality, dalvik, compass-geolocation

In my Android Application there's a cube which uses the compass to rotate, but the compass returns sometimes for a very small time a value which is completely different to the other values. Is there a way to solve it or must i write an Method to smooth the values.

Comment: found a solution: true values don't have fractional digits

Comment: check this following url out it's from stackOverflow and I guess cover your issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699417/android-compass-orientation-on-unreliable-low-pass-filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699417/android-compass-orientation-on-unreliable-low-pass-filter)

Answer (score 0):

you must implements a LowPassFilter, but if you need a more precision you must use a Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR.

Answer (score -1):

Shannon - Nyquist
You could have aliasing issues with 50-60Hz power. High sampling rates and filter afterwards.