# How to detect android device rotation parallel to the ground?

Tags: android, rotation, detection

As I know, the most of android devices allows to detect rotation by accelerometer, but I've noticed, that it doesn't detect rotation parallel to the ground. For example, if I put the device on a table and turn it around, no one of accelerometer indicators doesn't change.

[image]

At the picture, it's called "alfa" rotation. So how can I detect this kind of turning?

Comment: looping axis on X?

Comment: yes, turning by X axis

Comment: "alpha" describes rotation around z-axis, doesn't it?

Comment: Hmm... not by X axis, you're right. Also, I found compass feature in my android 5.0 device, so I can detect "alfa" rotation, but it's very unstable and not always shows right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sensing rotation around z-axis you need to implement a compass function. A good tutorial is [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSensor/article.html). To make the resulting values more stable you need to implement some algorithm which smoothes your incoming data ([averages over a queue of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911252/3356270), filtering outliers, etc.). Here is a good [overview](http://www.journal.deviantdev.com/android-compass-azimuth-calculating/).