# how to disable automatic magnetometer calibration?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, compass-geolocation, magnetometer

There are plenty of threads about how to calibrate the compass sensor by rotating in all 3 axes and that you can only really know if it's out of calibration by checking against GPS data. Like:

[Inbuilt sensor calibration functionality in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632370/inbuilt-sensor-calibration-functionality-in-android)

[Check and enable Magnetic sensor calibration in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012677/check-and-enable-magnetic-sensor-calibration-in-android)

[Compass give me crazy data, is calibration needed or it's the sensor broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462346/compass-give-me-crazy-data-is-calibration-needed-or-its-the-sensor-broken/9583998#9583998)

But my problem is this - I am using the magnetometer for other scientific purposes and I don't want it to recalibrate to the present environment because that would affect my measurements. Does the android OS only calibrate the sensor when the phone is moved more than a certain threshold or is it based on a timer or both? Is it possible to disable calibration altogether or would that require rooting the OS? thanks for any thoughts on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [uncalibrated magnetometer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html)?

The document says their measurement makes fewer jumps from the calibration